# display details base on selected option on drop down

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where I will chose from the first drop down then the second drop down will appear. After selecting in the second drop down, it must display some details. The details depends on which option he/she selected on the second drop down.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
Select: <select name="slist1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
 <option>- - -</option>
 <option value="pasta9-12">pasta 9-12</option>
 <option value="pasta15-18">pasta 15-18</option>
 <option value="entree">entree</option>
</select>
<span id="slist2"></span> <div id="scontent"></div>

<script>
var SList = new Object(); 
var txtsl2 = '<br> Select Category:';

SList.slist2 = {
 "pasta9-12": ['fettucine jacintha', 'penne bolognese', 'pasta verde', 'lasagna roll-ups','baked creamy cheesy penne', 'trio of sausages fettucine'],
 "pasta15-18": ['fettucine jacintha', 'penne bolognese', 'pasta verde', 'lasagna roll-ups','baked creamy cheesy penne', 'trio of sausages fettucine'],
 "entree": ['chicken', 'fillet', 'pork']
}; //when selected, it should display 'SList.scontent2'

SList.scontent = {
 "fettucine jacintha" : 'Price is 700',
 "penne bolognese":'Price is 700',
 "pasta verde":'Price is 700',
 "lasagna roll-ups":'Price is 700',
 "baked creamy cheesy penne":'Price is 700',
 "trio of sausages fettucine": 'Price is 700'
};

SList.scontent2 = {
 "fettucine jacintha" : 'Price is 1000',
 "penne bolognese":'Price is 1000',
 "pasta verde":'Price is 1000',
 "lasagna roll-ups":'Price is 1000',
 "baked creamy cheesy penne":'Price is 1000',
 "trio of sausages fettucine": 'Price is 1000'
}; // This should be displayed when 'pasta 15-18' is selected.

SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
  document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = '';     

  if(SList[slist][option]) {
    if(slist == 'scontent') document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = SList[slist][option];
    else if(slist == 'slist2') {
      var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
      for(var i=0; i<SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
        addata += '<option value="'+SList[slist][option][i]+'">'+SList[slist][option][i]+'</option>';
      }

      document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent\', this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
    }
  }
  else if(slist == 'slist2') {
    document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
  }
}
--></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to display SList.scontent when pasta 9-12 is selected. And display when  SList.scontent2 when pasta 15-18 is selected.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<body>
Select: <select name="slist1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
 <option>- - -</option>
 <option value="pasta9-12">pasta 9-12</option>
 <option value="pasta15-18">pasta 15-18</option>
 <option value="entree">entree</option>
</select>
<span id="slist2"></span> <div id="scontent"></div>

<script>
var SList = new Object(); 
var txtsl2 = '<br> Select Category:';

SList.slist2 = {
 "pasta9-12": ['fettucine jacintha', 'penne bolognese', 'pasta verde', 'lasagna roll-ups','baked creamy cheesy penne', 'trio of sausages fettucine'],
 "pasta15-18": ['fettucine jacintha', 'penne bolognese', 'pasta verde', 'lasagna roll-ups','baked creamy cheesy penne', 'trio of sausages fettucine'],
 "entree": ['chicken', 'fillet', 'pork']
}; //when selected, it should display 'SList.scontent2'

SList.scontent = {
 "fettucine jacintha" : 'Price is 700',
 "penne bolognese":'Price is 700',
 "pasta verde":'Price is 700',
 "lasagna roll-ups":'Price is 700',
 "baked creamy cheesy penne":'Price is 700',
 "trio of sausages fettucine": 'Price is 700'
};

SList.scontent2 = {
 "fettucine jacintha" : 'Price is 1000',
 "penne bolognese":'Price is 1000',
 "pasta verde":'Price is 1000',
 "lasagna roll-ups":'Price is 1000',
 "baked creamy cheesy penne":'Price is 1000',
 "trio of sausages fettucine": 'Price is 1000'
}; // This should be displayed when 'pasta 15-18' is selected.

SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
  document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = '';     

  if(SList[slist][option]) {
    if(slist == 'scontent'){
  document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = SList[slist][option];
 }else if(slist == 'scontent2'){
  document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = SList[slist][option];
 } else if(slist == 'slist2' && option=='pasta9-12') {
      var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
      for(var i=0; i<SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
        addata += '<option value="'+SList[slist][option][i]+'">'+SList[slist][option][i]+'</option>';
      }

      document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent\', this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
    }else if(slist == 'slist2' && option=='pasta15-18'){
  var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
      for(var i=0; i<SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
        addata += '<option value="'+SList[slist][option][i]+'">'+SList[slist][option][i]+'</option>';
      }

      document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent2\', this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
 }
  }
  else if(slist == 'slist2') {
    document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
  }
}
--></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this is what you are looking for.....

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, when I choose from the first drop down it doesn't display anymore the second drop down and the details.

I have tried placing your code inside:
SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
  document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = '';     

  if(SList[slist][option]) { YOUR CODE HERE }
  else if(slist == 'slist2') {
    document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
  }
}

implementing this one will display the details of 9-12' but not for the '5-18'. Thanks!

Comment: I had implemented drop down box with id and a little more code is added.
previously I had done some thing which is irrelevant to your requirement, now I think I got you.......

Answer (score 0):

I had come up with this one..

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- The first select list -->
Select: <select name="slist1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
 <option>- - -</option>
 <option value="pasta9-12">pasta 9-12</option>
 <option value="pasta15-18">pasta 15-18</option>
 <option value="entree">entree</option>
</select>
<!-- Tags for the second dropdown list, and for text-content -->
<span id="slist2"></span> <div name="scontent" id="scontent"></div> <div name="scontent2" id="scontent2"></div>

<script>
var SList = new Object(); 
var txtsl2 = '<br> Select Category:';

SList.slist2 = {
 "pasta9-12": ['fettucine jacintha', 'penne bolognese', 'pasta verde', 'lasagna roll-ups','baked creamy cheesy penne', 'trio of sausages fettucine'],
 "pasta15-18": ['Fettucine jacintha', 'penne bolognese', 'pasta verde', 'lasagna roll-ups','baked creamy cheesy penne', 'trio of sausages fettucine'],
 "entree": ['chicken', 'fillet', 'pork']
};

SList.scontent = {
 "fettucine jacintha" : 'Price is 700',
 "penne bolognese":'Price is 700',
 "pasta verde":'Price is 700',
 "lasagna roll-ups":'Price is 700',
 "baked creamy cheesy penne":'Price is 700',
 "trio of sausages fettucine": 'Price is 700'
};

SList.scontent2 = {
 "Fettucine jacintha" : 'Price is 1000',
 "penne bolognese":'Price is 1000',
 "pasta verde":'Price is 1000',
 "lasagna roll-ups":'Price is 1000',
 "baked creamy cheesy penne":'Price is 1000',
 "trio of sausages fettucine": 'Price is 1000'
};

SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
  document.getElementById('scontent' && 'scontent2').innerHTML = ''; 


  if(SList[slist][option]) {
    if(slist == 'scontent') document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = SList[slist][option];
    else if(slist == 'scontent2') document.getElementById('scontent2').innerHTML = SList[slist][option];

    else if(slist == 'slist2' && option=='pasta9-12') {
      var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
      for(var i=0; i<SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
        addata += '<option value="'+SList[slist][option][i]+'">'+SList[slist][option][i]+'</option>';
      }
      document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent\', this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
    }

    else if(slist == 'slist2' && option=='pasta15-18'){
        var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
      for(var i=0; i<SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
        addata += '<option value="'+SList[slist][option][i]+'">'+SList[slist][option][i]+'</option>';
      }
      document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent2\', this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
    }

  }
  else if(slist == 'slist2') {
    document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And it also worked :) but I think yours is a way more better. By the way, thanks a lot for helping!